# Update css of <li> when dropped into droppable area

Tags: jquery, css

I've implemented a droppable using jQuery like so below :

```
$( ".myVal" ).droppable({ drop: function( event, ui ) 
            { 

            } 
        });
```

I'm dragging a `<li>` element into the droppable area. Can I apply new css to the `<li>` just added when it is dropped, so instead of just text being dropped into the area, the text contains new css styling ?

Comment: the new li whould heredate the styles from the new container. just set #newContainer ul li{ prop:value; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( ".myVal" ).droppable({ drop: function( event, ui ) 
        { 
              $(this).find("li").addClass("newClass");
        } 
    });
```

I think this is what you need.

So:

**CSS**

```
.myVal ul li{
    //styles
}
```

is also good idea :)

Answer (score 2):

or you can just (as the li will heredate the styles from the new container)

```
/*OnlyCss*/
    .myVal ul li{
        color:red;
        background:blue;
    }
```

There is no need in doing it with jQuery, but if you still want to (But this only would make sense if the dropped element has to be different from the rest -in the new container-):

**Note:** *assuming the .draggable element is the* `li`

```
/*javascript*/
    $( ".myVal" ).droppable({ drop: function( event, ui ) 
            { 
                  ui.draggable.css({'color':'blue','background':'red'});
            } 
        });
```

or even

```
/*javascript+css*/
    $( ".myVal" ).droppable({ drop: function( event, ui ) 
            { 
                 ui.draggable.addClass('justDropped');
            } 
        }); 
   /*combined with*/ 
    .justDropped{
        color:red;
        background:blue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/ Under events there is a drop event you can use to do whatever transformation you want after dropping the element.